# rank function in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I'm trying to use the rank function and failing, could you guys give me some help?

here you can see some tries:

```
SELECT DBB.OBJECTDATABASENAME,
    DBB.OBJECTTABLENAME,
    DBB.objecttype AS TABLEKIND,
    DBB.LOGDATE,
    DBG.STATEMENTTYPE,
    rank(DBB.OBJECTDATABASENAME, DBB.OBJECTTABLENAME, DBB.objecttype desc) as row_rank
    --rank() over (order by DBB.OBJECTTABLENAME  desc) as row_rank
    --rank() over (order by DBB.OBJECTDATABASENAME, DBB.OBJECTTABLENAME, DBB.objecttype desc) as row_rank
    FROM PDCRINFO.DBQLOBJTBL_HST_v1620 DBB
    LEFT JOIN PDCRINFO.DBQLogTbl_HsT_v1620 DBG    
        ON DBG.QUERYID = DBB.QUERYID
        AND DBG.LOGDATE = DBB.LOGDATE
        AND DBG.PROCID = DBB.PROCID
    LEFT JOIN PDCRINFO.DBQLSQLTBL_HST QRY
        ON QRY.LOGDATE = DBB.LOGDATE
        AND QRY.QUERYID = DBB.QUERYID
        AND QRY.PROCID = DBB.PROCID
    WHERE DBB.LOGDATE = ('2022-11-27')
        AND  DBB.OBJECTTYPE IN ('Tab', 'Viw')
   GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

This is what I'm getting from my tries:

```
OBJECTDATABASENAME  OBJECTTABLENAME TABLEKIND   LOGDATE STATEMENTTYPE   row_rank
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_EXP1DB   STATUS_ACCUNT_CLI_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_EXP1DB   STATUS_ACCUNT_CLI_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
```

And here the outuput I'm looking for:

```
OBJECTDATABASENAME  OBJECTTABLENAME TABLEKIND   LOGDATE STATEMENTTYPE   row_rank
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  2
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  3
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  4
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  5
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  6
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  7
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  8
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  9
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  10
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  11
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  12
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  13
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  14
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  2
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  3
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  4
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_V Viw 27/11/2022  Update  5
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  2
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  3
PM_MSTRDB   STATUS_SUBPRODUTO_T Tab 27/11/2022  Select  4
PM_EXP1DB   STATUS_ACCUNT_CLI_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  1
PM_EXP1DB   STATUS_ACCUNT_CLI_V Viw 27/11/2022  Select  2
```

As you can see, the key `(OBJECTDATABASENAME,OBJECTTABLENAME,objecttype,LOGDATE,STATEMENTTYPE)` for the selected values mentioned in the where clause, returns 14 rows, and I want to enumerate these 14 rows.

Comment: I don't know Teradata, but - you didn't say what's the problem. You posted some code and output you want, but we don't know what happened when you ran that code. Did you get any error? If so, which one? If not, what happened?

Comment: I will amend my post...thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You need to clarify your question, and it sounds like maybe you need to get a better understanding of how window functions work. What columns are you using to group a set of rows together? Far as I can tell, your first 20 or so rows have the same values, but you are re-setting your row_rank.

Comment: You want to increment what you are calling ROW_RANK for every row even when key values match, so that's ROW_NUMBER not RANK. And there are 5 columns in your "key" where you want to "start over" so you need all 5 in a PARTITION BY clause - in other words you want to "number" the rows within a "partition" grouping. Also, ROW_NUMBER always requires some ORDER BY clause (whether or not you have PARTITION BY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/8Ex9CS5XErnUTmh7zcrOPg) says

> A rank r implies the existence of exactly r-1 rows with sort_expression value preceding it. **All rows having the same sort_expression value are assigned the same rank**.

That happened in your case - all rows share the same rank: `1`.

---

Did you try `row_number` instead?

```
select ...,
  row_number() over (order by DBB.OBJECTDATABASENAME, DBB.OBJECTTABLENAME, DBB.objecttype desc) rn
from ...
```

See (the same) documentation page; it explains `row_number` as well. Maybe you'll also need to include the `partition by` clause; can't tell.

---

You commented:

> I want to know is, for a key, how many row I have, and this for each key.

Isn't that the `count` function, then? Could be aggregation, or you could use its analytic form (I guess that's what you're looking for), e.g.

```
select ...
  count(*) over (partition by dbb.objectdatabasename)
from ...
```

(I don't know what "each key" actually means; maybe you should add additional columns into the `partition by` clause, or ...).

Comment: hey man, thanks for your anser, but, it's not what I'm looking for, your suggestion is just enumerating  each row, but I want to know is, for a key, how many row I have, and this for each key..

Comment: Are you, by any chance, looking for a **COUNT**, instead? See edited answer, maybe it'll help.

Comment: @gfernandes Your comment criticises the answer for `just enumerating each row` and yet your question literally says `I want to enumerate these 14 rows`. You seriously need to clarify your question.

Comment: hI Mat, thanks for your comment, I thought I was clear in my post, but I'll amend it again and maybe this time it will be clear for everyone

Comment: @Litterfoot, your count suggestion is one possible solution, yes, it's not what I want, but, it can give me something, since I'm not getting anything....thanks, I'll wait for others suggestion, if I didn't get anything, I will accept you answer as the answer for my question